# Using jQuery to change CSS attributes with delay

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i use **jQuery** to change the **CSS** attributes of a **HTML** element with delay.

Imagine this scenario. I have a `div` with `bg color` blue. I want it to fade out and when it fades back in i want the `bg color` to be red.

I tried this.

```
$("div").fadeOut().delay(500).css("background-color","red").fadeIn();
```

While fading out the div already changes the color to red before it fades in. It does not follow the sequence of chained events. How can I make this happen in one single line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have any function participate in the animation queue using the [`queue` function](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback-next-):

```
$("div")
    .fadeOut()
    .delay(500)
    .queue(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","red").dequeue();
    })
    .fadeIn();
```

Note the `dequeue` call within the callback, which is what tells jQuery to continue with the next thing in the queue.

Comment: Yes. This is what i wanted. Thanks for the explanation too

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $("div").css("background-color","red").fadeIn()
});
```

Comment: The `setTimeout` version was fine. This version won't delay the way the OP's code seems to want.

Comment: +1 for a good solution. However you took out my delay option. The 500ms seems to applied on the fadout now. and there is no delay :(