# CSS unhovering the text should not change to original colour

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently my screen's bg-color is white. When I hover over the row of table, bg-clor of the row is changing to blue color.

Now I want that blue colour remains like that even when I un-hover the text. 
The objective is to know what all rows have been hovered).

Comment: You can use `jQuery.addClass()`

Comment: 1.add a class with the blue color and remove it afterwards 
2.or save the original color in data and restore it
3.remove style attribute to restore background (if only teh bg color is inside)

Comment: As an aside, I'd recommend having a darker (or lighter) blue for the row that is currently hovered over. It'll make it easier to tell which row you're hovering over if you mouse over a bunch of rows and then come back.

Comment: For example, forking @logansarav's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/aslum/28WLE/1/

Comment: Thank you Salman. addClass() works in this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help you [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zv848/1/)

HTML

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px" id='my_table'>
  <tr>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Eve</td>
   <td>Jackson</td>
   <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#my_table tr td').mouseenter(function(){ 
    $(this).parent('tr').addClass('blue'); 
});
```

OR

```
$('#my_table tr').mouseenter(function(){ 
    $(this).addClass('blue'); 
});
```

CSS

```
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: I accepted the answer. Thanks. Just a small question related to the same question. Can we have a delay of 1 or 2 seconds before changing the colour?

Comment: yes, you can use [`delay`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438761/using-jquery-to-change-css-attributes-with-delay) or [`settimeout`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421985/delay-not-working-when-changing-background-color-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try hover function of jquery for this. good for performance point of view.

```
$('#my_table tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('blue');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use css ":hover" selector? This should work in all new browsers.

Edit: Oh, my mistake. I should read the question more precise.

In your case I suggest:

```
$('#tableId tr').mouseover(function(e){
    $( this ).css('background-color','#00F');  
});
```